# Is there any way to create an event which starts a Function whenever the Rigidbody is made Kinematic True?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

basically, what my question is that, Is there any way to create an event which does something when ever the Rigidbody attached to the Gameobject is made Kinematic True?

I have a problem where when ever some object is made kinematic true, i have to make the same object kinematic false after 1 or 2 seconds

Comment: You can use a bool for if the Kinematic is true or false. `If(kinematic == true) {//do your thing}`

Comment: You can check for it in the Update function. if (yourGameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic == true)
        {
            yourGameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
        }

If you want to set it after 1 or 2 seconds you can put the set function either in IEnumerator or call it from invoke with wait time

Comment: thanks @bilal1409,although this was not what i was looking for, but it has solved my problem. Could you write this as an aswer so i can mention rank it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important: This method requires that you change the way you reference the rigidbody's isKinematic variable from all your code.**

**First you create a property to set isKinematic instead of directly accessing through rigidbody.**

```
private Rigidbody rb;

public bool IsKinematic
{
    get
    {
        return rb.isKinematic;
    }
    set
    {
        rb.isKinematic = value;
    }
}
```

**Now you declare an event that fires whenever isKinematic changes.**

```
public event EventHandler OnKinematicValueChange;
```

and modify your isKinematic property to:

```
public bool IsKinematic
{
    get
    {
        return rb.isKinematic;
    }
    set
    {
        // Similar to if (OnKinematicValueChange != null) OnKinematicValueChange(this, EventArgs.Empty)
        OnKinematicValueChange?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        rb.isKinematic = value;
    }
}
```

This make sures that everytime isKinematic is changed through the property, the OnKinematicValueChange event is fired.

**Finally, make sure to subscribe to the event in Awake/Start methods so it fires everytime isKinematic is changed.**

```
private void Awake()
{
    OnKinematicValueChange += OnKinematicValueChangeHandler;

    // or

    OnKinematicValueChange += (sender, args) => 
    {
        // Event handling stuff
        // Disable isKinematic after 2 seconds with Coroutine etc.
    };
{

private void OnKinematicValueChangeHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
{
    // Event handling stuff
    // Disable isKinematic after 2 seconds with Coroutine etc.
{
```

From this point, you need to change all your references to the RigidBody's isKinematic variable by using the IsKinematic property instead.

Make sure to also check for Rigidbody null within the property and provide handling code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for it in the Update function.

```
if (yourGameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic == true)    
{
    yourGameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false; 
}
```

If you want to set it after 1 or 2 seconds you can put the set function either in [IEnumerator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) or call it from [Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) with wait time